# Android webview with admob, admob not displaying

Tags: java, android, webview, admob

I am trying to make a simple webview with admob on the bottom of the screen, everything works, but admob is not displaying.

I am new to android studio and admob, so please forgive me if I made a mistake on the code or if anything is missing.

Here's my code:

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="app.atlasdatabase">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package app.atlasdatabase;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.atlasdatabase);
        WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setDatabaseEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
        myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="atlasdb.atlasdatabase.MainActivity">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/atlasdatabase"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_home_footer"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found the problem!

Following the google guide here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start

After I added the dependencies to the gradle script and added this code to the MainActivity.java it worked:

```
AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add dependency in gradle file.

Then you need to initialize add view and set Ad id both in xml and java code.
Please follow [Google AdMob Guide](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start) for more details.